# FCM integration issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are following the integration steps from FCM link through cocoapods
we are able to receive the token through the following line:

```
if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
```

but after when we try to connect to FCM by the following code:

```
    func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")

            print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            let userInfo = ["error": error?.localizedDescription]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: self.registrationKey), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)

        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
```

we are getting the below error:

> Unable to connect with FCM. Optional(Error Domain=com.google.fcm
>   Code=2001 "(null)")

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did ur issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple , donot try to connect the FCM again if its already connected - This was doing the mess.

So i just had a flag that avoids connecting FCM if its already connected

Comment: I am very new to push notifications.Please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198651/xcode-8-1-push-notifications-in-swift-2-3-with-firebase-integration-not-getting. Please help me

Comment: Yes it got resolved , i will try to answer your query in sometime

Comment: Thank u for ur reply