# Xcode 8.1 Push Notifications in swift 2.3 with firebase integration not getting?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with Xcode 8.1 & swift 2.3 here I am using firebase integration for getting push notifications.I don't know why i am not getting notifications..
    My code:

```
     func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
                    authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_,_ in })

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
                 application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            } else
            {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            FIRApp.configure()

            // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                                 selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                                 name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,
                                                                 object: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
    return true
    }

  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
    {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
    {
        print(deviceToken)
        let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
        var tokenString = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
            tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
        }

        //Tricky line
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)
        print("Device Token:", tokenString)

    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        // Print the error to console (you should alert the user that registration failed)
        print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: UNUserNotificationCenter) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
            let deviceFCMToken: String = refreshedToken
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(deviceFCMToken, forKey: "FCMToken")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isFCMTokenAvailable")
             //UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    func connectToFcm()
    {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }


extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate
{
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)
    {

        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Uma. Try to remove application.registerForRemoteNotifications() from  "didRegisterUserNotificationSettings". And remove your if clause from "if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {" leave only the "else" statement logic.

Comment: Ok . I will try nd let u know

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa..If i remove means i am getting error as add #available.

Comment: Did you try using the Notification console to send a simple message to your app?

Comment: @chengsam..I have tried,notification had come.But when my server sent this is not coming

Comment: @chengsam.. FCM delegate extension is called when i get notification but UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate is never called ..

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Note that if you send Data message, `applicationReceivedRemoteMessage` will be called. For Notification message, `userNotificationCenter(_ center: , willPresent: , withCompletionHandler:` will be called.

Comment: @chengsam.. what is data message. applicationReceivedRemoteMessage is not calling

Comment: What means by FCM delegate extension is called?

Answer (score 1):

Since you requested me on *another thread's comment section*, I am posting this working set of code with the same configuration you have mentioned:

```
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //############## FIREBASE ##################

        registerForPushNotifications(application)
        FIRApp.configure()
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NSNotificationCenter
            .defaultCenter()
            .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.tokenRefreshNotification),
                         name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)

        //############ FIREBASE END ################  

        return true
    }


    //MARK: - FIREBASE START

    //######################################## FIREBASE START ###########################################

    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
                if (granted)
                {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
                else{
                    //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
                }
            })
        }

        else{ //If user is not on iOS 10 use the old methods we've been using
            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
                forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        }
    }



    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        if notificationSettings.types != .None {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
        var tokenString = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
            tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
        }

        //Tricky line
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
        print("Device Token:", tokenString)
        print("Firebase Token:",FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token())
    }

    // [START receive_message]


    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        //Handle the notification
        //Use this place to handle
    }


    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        //Handle the notification
        //Use this place to handle the notification
        print(response)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        print(userInfo)
    }

    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        //FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        //FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]


    //###################################### FIREBASE ##########################################
    //######################################## END #############################################
}
```

**Payload Format:**

```
[aps: {
    alert =     {
        body = "Some message.";
        title = "Some title";
     };
     category = " ";
 }, Name: ios, gcm.message_id: 0:1474608925388897%17bce75117bc5555]
```

Comment: can u tell me how does the payload look like example.

Comment: %@ [from: 730307127978, itemId: 5858bd87e4b0d0e761b1acb6, viewed: false, createdTS: 1482211014645, notificationToName: Uma Madhavi, notificationType: ISUPPORT_UPDATED, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, actionByName: Uma Madhavi, notificationTo: 572c5ae7e4b08bce2f9641a7, actionBy: 572c5ae7e4b08bce2f9641a7].. This is the format  i am getting from server.

Comment: This is not clearly viewable, add it to your question. I have added the format in my answer.What is %@ in here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131340/discussion-between-uma-madhavi-and-mr-bista).

Answer (score 0):

@Uma Madhavi
Try adding below method

**SWIFT**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
```

}